# Problem with django rest framework APIview in pythonanywhere

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I built an APIView to handle login.
I use post method to send email and passwrod like below

```
class LoginApi(views.APIView):

permission_classes = (AllowAny,) # Adding permission to everyone

def post(self,request):
    email = request.data['email']
    password = request.data['password']
    ...
```

This  works in my own system but when in push this to pythonanywhere the shape of request.data change like this:

in my system :

```
{"email":"email","password":"1234"}
```

but in pythonanywhere is:

```
<QueryDict: {'_content_type': ['application/json'], '_content': ['{"email":"email","password":"1234"}\r\n']}>
```

my django version and rest-framework is the same with pythonanywhere.
just my python version is 3.10 but pythonanywhere is 3.9. but I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: Can you compare the requests' headers locally and on PythonAnywhere?  The parser used will be determined by the `Content-Type` header, as per [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)

Comment: @caseneuve yes it's where the problem comes .I'll post the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I sent wrong parser so I got wrong data in server[(this is parser docs)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).